# "Enriched" permutation graph: pseudo-unique map?

Tags: graph-theory

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_graph).

Choose a permutation $P$ of $\{1,\dots,n\}$. Draw the permutation graph $G=G(P)$. Add information with a third color to get an "enriched" permutation graph $G'$:

1. For obtaining $G'$, draw $G$ in blue and its complement in red.
2. Now, if (say) something like $[\dots 1\dots 2\dots 3\dots]$ occurs in $P$, by transitivity the knowledge of $1<3$ is redundant for describing $P$. Of course not for $G$! (Assume $G$ is a blue triangle, then uniquely $P=[321]$ but any of the vertices could "represent" any of the numbers.
3. For $G'$, draw these "transitive lines" in yellow (or not at all).

The question is now: Given $G'$, can $P$ be uniquely reconstructed (which is usually impossible already for $G$, although *some* $P$ can be easily found in $O(n)$ time) in the even stronger sense that any vertex of $G'$ uniquely corresponds to a number $i\in P$? (For example, $G$ being a blue triangle leads to $G'$ being a blue-blue-green one, and it is obvious which vertices of $G'$ correspond to $1,2,3$.)

1. Of course, not any $G'$ is a graph of some $P$, even worse so than with $G$. You may not even reconstruct some $G$ from $G'$ if a yellow line must turn out blue and red at the same time. Assume $G'$ is valid, i.e. *some* $P$ exists.
2. Drawing $P$ as grid point set $S=i,P_i$, you easily see that if $P$ is a solution to a given $G'$, so is $P$ obtained from $S$ being rotated by $180°$ in the plane or diagonally. I call these (up to 3) alternative solutions "trivial".
   [image: "trivially" different permutation]
3. See image. If $P$ is "splittable" (what is the terminus technicus for such a permutation?), construction 2 can be applied to each part of $P$ leading to the same $G'$. I call these alternative solutions "trivial" either.

Big question: Does a $G'$ exist which has two non-trivial solutions $P,P'$?

If no, this would be very nice, since then the dynamic binary search tree problem could be completely formulated on a graph: "trivial" alternative $P$ are no problem as a set of optimal solutions for a "splittable" $P$ (in the Demaine view of the problem) can be merged with $O(n)$ overhead, which is irrelevant as the optimal solution needs at least $O(n)$ anyway.